# Object of class Years cannot be converted to string error in Object oriented php

Tags: php

i'm new to OO in php. i was working with this code and there was an error "object of the class years cannot be converted in string". Now i kind of know what the error is saying but i'm not able to figure the solution out. And yeah I've checked every other question regarding this. Somebody please help me. Here is the code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
$name=$_POST['name'];
$age=$_POST['age'];
$hrs=$_POST['hrs'];

class Years
{
    const divid=24;
    public function __construct($nme,$ag,$hr)
    {
        $ans= ($ag * $hr)/self::divid;
        return $ans;

    }
    public function calc()
    {
        return "ok";
    }
}

echo $yrs= new Years($name,$age,$hrs);


}

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My Unconcious Life</h1>
<form method="post">
    Your Name:<br />
    <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
    Your Age:<br />
    <input type="text" name="age" /><br />
    Hours slept per night:<br />
    <input type="text" name="hrs" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Calculate" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you have to try to echo an object, give it a [__toString()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) method

Comment: But don't try to return anything from a constructor, executing the constructor creates the object instance, and that's what will be assigned to `$yrs`.... return from a constructor is ignored

Comment: @MarkBaker, so what you're saying is that i should make another function and process the data in it, and then call it like $yrs->anotherFunction(){}. is  this way is better?

Comment: Not quite.... if you have a `__toString()` method, it's a __magic__ method that's executed if you try to echo an object instance (e.g. `echo $yrs;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your class. Let's see:

```
class Years
{
    const divid=24;
    public function __construct($nme,$ag,$hr)
    {
        $ans= ($ag * $hr)/self::divid;
        return $ans;

    }
    public function calc()
    {
        return "ok";
    }
}

echo $yrs= new Years($name,$age,$hrs);
```

Problem #1: [constructors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) do not return anything.

In order to make your class return something, you should create an attribute and then return it with a getter method:

```
class Years
{
    const divid=24;
    private $ans;

    public function __construct($nme,$ag,$hr)
    {
        $this->ans = ($ag * $hr)/self::divid;
    }

    public function getAns()
    {
        return $this->ans;
    }

    public function calc()
    {
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

Problem #2: Your constructor has unused arguments.

Why are you passing a `$nme` (notice the typo) argument to the constructor if it is not needed?

```
class Years
{
    const divid=24;
    private $ans;

    public function __construct($ag,$hr)
    {
        $this->ans = ($ag * $hr)/self::divid;
    }

    public function getAns()
    {
        return $this->ans;
    }

    public function calc()
    {
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

Problem #3: in order to convert an object to a string, your class should implement the `__toString()` method:

```
class Years
{
    const divid=24;
    private $ans;

    public function __construct($ag,$hr)
    {
        $this->ans = ($ag * $hr)/self::divid;
    }

    public function getAns()
    {
        return $this->ans;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getAns();
    }

    public function calc()
    {
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

---

Despite of that, I'd say that your fundamental issue is that you are creating objects when they are not needed.

If you want just to transform units of time, all you need is a function:

```
function getYears($ag, $hr) {
    return $ag * $hr / 24;
}
```

This is what it should be. This is not a problem to be solved with object orientation, a simple function call will do it.

Always remember to [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to code this would be

```
<?php

class Years
{
    private $divid;

    // although this is
    public function __construct($div)
    {        
        $this->divid = $div;
    }

    public function calc($ag,$hr)
    {
        return ($ag * $hr) / $this->divid;
    }
}


if( isset($_POST['sub'], $_POST['age'], $_POST['hrs'], $_POST['name']) ){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $age=$_POST['age'];
    $hrs=$_POST['hrs'];

    $yrs = new Years(24);
    $result = $yrs->calc($age,$hrs)

    echo "The result is $result";
} else {
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My Unconcious Life</h1>
<form method="post">
    Your Name:<br />
    <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
    Your Age:<br />
    <input type="text" name="age" /><br />
    Hours slept per night:<br />
    <input type="text" name="hrs" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Calculate" />

</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
}
?>
?>
```

Comment: surely though this is outputting content before the html tag and thus rendering it invalid?

Comment: @RamRaider Good point. I was rather concentrating on the problems with the class and usage of the class, but I will amend now you pointed that out

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different than the other answer. a little easier.

```
class Years
{
    const divid=24;
    public $ans;

    public function __construct($nme,$ag,$hr)
    {
        $this->ans = ($ag * $hr)/self::divid;

    }
    public function calc()
    {
        return "ok";
    }
}

$yrs= new Years($name,$age,$hrs);
echo $yrs->ans;
```